# Why am I getting the same values for test accuracy and balenced accuracy for all the 10 folds?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

For each fold test accuracy and balanced test accuracy is different, but the values are same.
For example, Fold 1, test accuracy is 86, balanced test accuracy is 86.
For Fold 2, test accuracy is 90, balanced test accuracy is 90
For fold 3, test accuracy is 70.555, test accuracy is 70.555...Here is my code

````
fold_no = 1
reports = []
accuracies = []
sensitivities = []
specificities = []
test_accuracy = []
for train, test in kfold.split(X_train, y_train):

  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Conv3D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3))
  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer='l2'))
  model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer='l2')) 
  model.add(Dropout(0.3))
  model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_regularizer='l2'))

  # Compile the model
  model.compile(loss=tensorflow.keras.losses.mean_squared_error,
                optimizer=tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate),
                metrics=['accuracy'])```

  history = model.fit(X_train[train], y_train[train],
                      batch_size=batch_size,
                      epochs=no_epochs,
                      verbose=verbosity, validation_data=(X_train[test], y_train[test]))

  # Compute the classification report for the testing set
  y_pred = model.predict(X_test, verbose = 0)
  c = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
  test_accuracy.append(c[1])
  report = classification_report(y_test, (y_pred>0.5), output_dict=True)
  from sklearn.metrics import balanced_accuracy_score
  bal_acc=balanced_accuracy_score(y_test,(y_pred>0.5))
  print("balenced acc is " + str(bal_acc))

  # Extract the sensitivity and specificity values from the report
  sensitivity = report["1"]["recall"]
  specificity = report["0"]["recall"]
  sensitivities.append(sensitivity)
  specificities.append(specificity)

  print(specificity))  
  print(sensitivity))
````

Comment: It's unknowable without seeing your data. For binary classification this can happen if class frequencies are already balanced (number of 0s == number of 1s in the test set).

Comment: Yes, I am using it binary classification, and the class frequencies are perfectly balanced. Maybe, that is causing it. I just wanted to be sure that I didn't do anything wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When classes are balanced to begin with, balanced accuracy and accuracy are the same:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, balanced_accuracy_score

y_true = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]    # 4 negatives, 4 positives
y_pred = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]

print(accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred), balanced_accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred))
# 0.75 0.75
```